# Type erasure with generic functions

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `protocol` with two functions, one of them are taking `associatedtype` as parameter value and another is a generic function.

Now, I'm trying to implement a TypeErasure for my protocol, but can't get the generic function implemented.

**My protocol looks like below -:**

```
public protocol CBLProtocol {
    associatedtype QueryType
    func fetchData<T:Decodable>(modelType:T.Type,_ queryType: QueryType,_ parameters:String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs>
    func purgeCBDocument(_ queryType:QueryType) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,CBErrorMsgs>
}
```

**Concrete type implementing protocol -:**

```
class Test:CBLProtocol{
 // MARK: fetchCBData()
    public  func fetchData<T>(modelType: T.Type,
                              _ queryType: CBInstanceTypes,
                              _ parameters:String = "") -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs> where T : Decodable {
        return CBFetchDataRepo.fetchCbLiteData(modelType: T.self)
    }

func purgeCBDocument(_ queryType:QueryType) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,CBErrorMsgs>{}

}
```

**Type Erasure -:**

```
class  AnyCblHandler<V>: CBLProtocol {
    
    typealias QueryType = V
    
    private let fetchData: (T.Type,V,String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs>
    private let purgeCBDocument: (V) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,CBErrorMsgs>
    
    init<U: CBLProtocol>(_ handler: U) where U.QueryType == V {
        self.purgeCBDocument = handler.purgeCBDocument
        self.fetchData = handler.fetchData
    }
    
    func fetchData<T>(modelType: T.Type, _ queryType: V, _ parameters: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs> where T : Decodable {
        fetchData(modelType,queryType,parameters)
    }
    
    func purgeCBDocument(_ queryType: V) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, CBErrorMsgs> {
        purgeCBDocument(queryType)
    }
}
```

In above code I'm getting error for can't find Type **T**, which is obvious, but I don't know how to satisfy compiler here.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Downvoted for using this Objective-C "CB" stuff instead of making a minimal reproducible example. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that T is defined (made concrete) when the class in initialised, from the value implied in handler.fetchData in init. This is then set for the class and so the func fetchData can not be generic over T anymore. I have  T in the class declaration as T: Deccodable and renamed the variable fetchDataVAR, as this seemed to be causing an issue having the same name as the function.

In the code sample below, by making the func fetchData no longer generic, the complier warning is silenced. The problem now is the class no longer conforms to the protocol, as the protocol is asking for a generic func.

```
class  AnyCblHandler<V , T: Decodable>: CBLProtocol {  // Getting warning: Type 'AnyCblHandler<V, T>' does not conform to protocol 'CBLProtocol'

typealias QueryType = V

private let fetchDataVAR: (T.Type , V , String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs>
private let purgeCBDocument: (V) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,CBErrorMsgs>

init<U: CBLProtocol>(_ handler: U) where U.QueryType == V {
    self.purgeCBDocument = handler.purgeCBDocument
    self.fetchDataVAR = handler.fetchData
}

func fetchData(modelType: T.Type , _ queryType: V, _ parameters: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs> {
    return fetchDataVAR(modelType ,queryType , parameters)
}

func purgeCBDocument(_ queryType: V) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, CBErrorMsgs> {
    purgeCBDocument(queryType)
}
```

}

I have struggled to find a full solution. Basically, by deriving T when the class is initialised you cannot then have a generic function taking any other T. The error you are getting if you make the function generic is "Cannot convert value of type 'T.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'"

Although a little obtuse, it is saying that the generic T in the function when called cannot be guaranteed to be the same T as defined in fetchDataVAR (which was set when the class was initialised), and they need to be the same T.type as you pass the modelType from one to the other.

No solution yet but I hope this helps. If you can make the protocol requirement not need a generic function it should be solved.

```
func fetchData<T>(modelType: T.Type , _ queryType: V, _ parameters: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], CBErrorMsgs> {
    return fetchDataVAR(modelType ,queryType , parameters)  // Cannot convert value of type 'T.Type' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
}
```